# Algolia Instantsearch Array display

Tags: arrays, algolia

I am having problems getting my array to display in algola and even the demo has problems with this. Here is the link to the demo.
https://www.algolia.com/realtime-search-demo/quick-demo

I am trying to get Skills.SkillName to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo generator is definitely limited and has not been designed to handle all use-cases. The most important part is that it displays correctly in the Index tab of your Algolia dashboard.

Then, in your front-end, using this array will definitely depend on your implementation. If you're using a `mustache` templating engine (like `Hogan.js` which is used in [Algolia's `instantsearch.js`](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/)), displaying the list of `Skills.SkillName` can be done using a template along those lines:

```
Skills:
<ul>
{{#Skills}}
  <li>{{SkillName}}</li>
{{/Skills}}
</ul>
```

[Link to the `mustache` doc](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html).